# Custom ordering in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-order-by

Is there a way to have a custom order by query in sqlite?

For example, I have essentially an enum

```
_id|Name|Key
------------
1 | One | Named
2 | Two | Contributing
3 | Three | Named
4 | Four | Key
5 | Five | Key
6 | Six | Contributing
7 | Seven | Named
```

And the 'key' columns have ordering. Say Key > Named > Contributing.

Is there a way to make

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Key`

return something to the effect of

```
_id|Name|Key
------------
4 | Four | Key
5 | Five | Key
1 | One | Named
3 | Three | Named
7 | Seven | Named
2 | Two | Contributing
6 | Six | Contributing
```

this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite and custom order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  SELECT _id, Name, Key 
    FROM my_table t 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN key = 'Key' THEN 0 
              WHEN key = 'Named' THEN 1 
              WHEN key = 'Contributing' THEN 2 END, id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of CASE's (or complicated set of conditions), Adam's solution may result in an extremely large query.

SQLite does allow you to write your own functions (in C++). You could write a function to return values similar to the way Adam does, but because you're using C++, you could work with a much larger set of conditions (or separate table, etc).

Once the function is written, you can refer to it in your SELECT as if it were a built-in function:

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY MyOrder(Key)

Comment: This is actually on Android. Do you know if that's possible for android as well?

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or some other language? AFAIK, all platforms are built from the same C source code, so probably. The sqlite3_create_function() is used to 'register' your function with SQLite (one of its parameters is a pointer to your C function). Once registered, you can use the new function in your SQL statements.

Comment: hey Marc Bernier can help me out by giving an example how to create custom function and use sqlite function I search in sqlite site but didnt understood anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try (not tested on my side but relying on a technique I previously used):

```
ORDER BY KEY = "Key" DESC,
         KEY = "Named" DESC,
         KEY = "Contributing" DESC
```