# About the efficient query for displaying on ListView

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, listview

I'm a beginner of SQL.
I would like to display sqlite data on Android listview. The table has the following structure.

```
| _id | name | data | ...
---------------------
|   0 |   A  |  abc |
|   1 |   B  |  def |
|   2 |   C  |  ghi | ...
|   3 |   D  |  jkl |
|   4 |   E  |  mno |
```

So, when the user inputs [C, B, D], I want to display name and data column in **user's order**.
For example,

ListView

```
---------------------
     C     ghi
---------------------
     B     def
---------------------
     D     jkl
---------------------
```

I'm torn between using ArrayAdapter and CursorAdapter now.

Should I do SELECT 3 times, store values in array, and use ArrayAdapter? Or, can fulfill my demands with SELECT once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be a bit complicated but it can be done in a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 
  CASE name
    WHEN 'C' THEN 0
    WHEN 'B' THEN 1
    WHEN 'D' THEN 2
  END
```

You'll have to construct the query according to the user input ofcourse
.
[Look more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

You can fulfill your demands with SELECT query. Your query would look like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE name IN ('C', 'B', 'D');"
```

Comment: Is the order (C, B, D) guaranteed? order is important.

Comment: i'm not sure about order. but you may give a try in ADB's SQLite to verify the order