# SQLite returning data in custom order

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm using an SQLite query (in an iOS application) as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tblStations WHERE StationID IN ('206','114','113','111','112','213','214','215','602','603','604')
```

However, I'm getting the resulting data in either descending or ascending order, when what I really want is for the data to be returned in the order I've specified in the IN clause.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to get data by order?

Comment: With my little knowledge of SQL, this is not possible without using some sort of trick

Comment: You can keep an array of stationIDs in the order you want and then using `NSComparator` the resultsArray can be sorted.

Comment: You could, of course, just fetch the values sequentially.  Use a compiled statement and it should run about as fast as the above, if there's an index on StationID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite and custom order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by)

Answer (score 5):

A trivial way to sort the results

```
NSArray *stationIDs = @[@206,@114,@113,@111,@112,@213,@214,@215,@602,@603,@604];

NSArray *stations = @[@{@"Id":@(604)},@{@"Id":@(603)},@{@"Id":@(602)},@{@"Id":@(215)},
                      @{@"Id":@(214)},@{@"Id":@(213)},@{@"Id":@(112)},@{@"Id":@(111)},
                      @{@"Id":@(113)},@{@"Id":@(114)},@{@"Id":@(206)}];

stations = [stations sortedArrayUsingComparator:
            ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * dict1, NSDictionary *dict2)
{
    NSUInteger index1 = [stationIDs indexOfObject:dict1[@"Id"]];
    NSUInteger index2 = [stationIDs indexOfObject:dict2[@"Id"]];
    return [@(index1) compare:@(index2)];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to map these station IDs to another value that is suitable for sorting:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStations
WHERE StationID IN ('206','114','113','111','112',
                    '213','214','215','602','603','604')
ORDER BY CASE StationID
         WHEN '206' THEN 1
         WHEN '114' THEN 2
         WHEN '113' THEN 3
         WHEN '111' THEN 4
         WHEN '112' THEN 5
         WHEN '213' THEN 6
         WHEN '214' THEN 7
         WHEN '215' THEN 8
         WHEN '602' THEN 9
         WHEN '603' THEN 10
         WHEN '604' THEN 11
         END
```

Comment: This solution only works if you don't have repeated values in the list, otherwise the results will only show the first occurrence.

Comment: @neowinston ID's should be primary keys, and thus cannot have repeated values.

Comment: @Vivid Kraig Good observation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

A second way of doing it (the first one being with `CASE WHEN ... THEN END` as already stated in another answer) is:

```
ORDER BY StationID=206 DESC,
         StationID=114 DESC,
         StationID=113 DESC,
         StationID=111 DESC,
         StationID=112 DESC,
         StationID=213 DESC,
         etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any means of returning SQL data in an order that isn't ascending, descending or random (either intentionally so, or simply in the order the database engine chooses to return the data).

As such, it would probably make sense to simply fetch all of the data returned by the SQLite query and store it in an `NSDictionary` keyed on the StationID value. It would then be trivial to retrieve in the order you require.

Answer (score 1):

add an additional column to use for sorting. e.g. add a column named "sortMePlease". Fill this column according to your needs, meaning for the row for stationID 216 enter 1, for 114 enter 2, .... and finally add "ORDER BY sortMePlease ASC" to your query.