# Query Sqlite Database by specific/custom ordering?

Tags: sqlite, cursor, sql-order-by

Let's say I got a table, something like this:

***ID | TITLE***
1  |  AAA
2  |  BBB
3  |  CCC
4  |  DDD
5  |  EEE
...
...

I want to perform a query, using IN opeator, while preserving the order of the IN Arguments

```
database.query("some_table", null, ID + " IN("+ idsStr+")", null, null, null, null);
```

For example, if the query is "select from some_table where id in (4,1,5) ...(order by???)", I want that the returned cursor to be sorted as 4,1,5

Is it possible? how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite and custom order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

Tested, works:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE _id IN(4, 1, 5) 
ORDER BY
CASE _id
WHEN '4' THEN 1
WHEN '1' THEN 2
WHEN '5' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END, _id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested user3249477 answer above, but assuming the SQL is correct (it looks okay), then SQLiteDatabase has a rawquery method that returns a cursor.

`database.rawquery("SELECT * FROM books WHERE _id IN(4, 1, 5) ORDER BY CASE _id WHEN '4' THEN 1 WHEN '1' THEN 2 WHEN '5' THEN 3");`

Comment: Is this statement affects on qeury time? lets say I need to query 10k items? how's qeury speed affected? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A second way of doing it (the first one being with `CASE WHEN ... THEN END` as already stated in other answers) is:

```
ORDER BY ID=4 DESC,
         ID=1 DESC,
         ID=5 DESC
```