# Sorting query results by order of selection arguments in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

So what I am doing is:
There are songs, in a specific order.
I am storing a list of IDs of the songs so that I can fetch them later, in the same order.

I am storing the list of IDs inside the variable `in`, and this is how I am fetching them:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( in.length * 2 - 1 );
        sb.append( "?" );
        for ( int i = 1; i < in.length; i ++ )
        {
            sb.append( ",?" );
        }
        String strIn = sb.toString( );

songCursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, TRACK_COLUMNS,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID + " IN (" + strIn + ")", in, null );
```

Everything is working fine, the only problem is, the list is in a different order than as was stored. Here I can't use sort order since obviously the order in which I want is not specified. I want it to be in the order in which it was stored but I have no idea how I can do it.

Also this is the information given while hovering over the query, so that explains the reason, but I don't have a solution.

> selectionArgs You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced
>   by the values from selectionArgs, in the order that they appear in the
>   selection.

For example:

[image]

In the above picture, I am storing the ids of all the songs in the order in which they are.

[image]

But when I am retrieving them, the order is changed.

Comment: Order by the `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED` column, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: no no, the order has to match the order in which the songs/ids were added 
suppose there is a list of songs

Comment: Ok. Added to what, then?

Comment: now I store the ids, and then retrieve them later
the original order of the songs should be maintained ,which  is not happening

Comment: the order has to match the order in which the songs/ids were added suppose there is a list of songs 
now I store the ids, and then I try to retrieve them later . The original order in which the song ids were stored  should be maintained ,which is not happening

Comment: If `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC"` isn't what you want for the last argument in the `query()` call, then I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: so you probably want to change `Cursor#moveToPosition` method behavior, then see `CursorWrapper` class

Comment: That's not how your question reads. Please edit to clarify that you mean sorting by the order of IDs in the query.

Comment: it is not exactly what i want ,but it somewhat explains it

Comment: Did you try building an _order by_ String like the linked post describes?

Comment: @MikeM. I have redescribed my situation above. Please have a look

Comment: I think that was a wrong link

Comment: No, that post describes exactly the same situation.

Comment: @MikeM. please have a look at the pictures, I have explained my situation

Comment: Yeah, the pictures don't explain it as well as the text did. So you're getting the IDs for the songs as you're inserting them, yes? And those are what make up the `in` array?

Comment: I dont think I understood you properly.

Comment: There are a bunch of songs, a user plays,okay?
Now they can be in any order. I want to provide the user with a functionality "Last played" 
this last played should show the songs last played by the user in the exact same order. 
For which I am storing the song ids. and then displaying them after querying,but while displaying we can both see that the order hasn't been the same as it was before storing

Comment: I think I got ya. You're storing the last played IDs in your app. You just need the query to come back with the Cursor in the order you're giving the IDs.

Comment: Ok, gimme a minute to test.

Comment: Thanks :) Was my explanation really bad ?

Comment: No, I think we were just repeating the same thing back to each other, but it wasn't clicking. Anyway, I tested the code below, and it works for me, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621076), the code below builds a `CASE` expression for the `sortOrder` argument in the `query()` call, alongside the `selection` argument.

```
StringBuilder inStr = new StringBuilder(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
    .append(" IN (?");

StringBuilder orderStr = new StringBuilder("CASE ")
    .append(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
    .append(" WHEN ")
    .append(in[0])
    .append(" THEN 0");

for (int i = 1; i < in.length; i++) {
    inStr.append(",?");

    orderStr.append(" WHEN ")
        .append(in[i])
        .append(" THEN ")
        .append(i);
}

inStr.append(")");

orderStr.append(" END, ")
    .append(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
    .append(" ASC");

Cursor songCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                               TRACK_COLUMNS,
                                               inStr.toString(),
                                               in,
                                               orderStr.toString());
```

The `CASE` expression is essentially assigning an alias value to each ID to sort by, rather than sorting by the actual ID value. No matter what the first ID is in the selection, its alias value will be `0`, the second will be `1`, the third `2`, etc. Ordering by these values ascendingly, the resulting `Cursor` will be in the order of the IDs passed in the selection.

Comment: working, but can you please add an explaination ? of what's happening?