# SQLite ORDER BY Without Special Ordering

Tags: sqlite

If I have a column in a SQLite table like "Color" with values like "Red," "Blue," and "Green" and use ORDER BY Color, it'll automatically order the colors alphabetically.

Is there any way to specify the order of the colors?  For instance, if I specified:

```
ORDER BY Color ('Green', 'Red', 'Blue')
```

to get the results ordered so the rows with Green are first, followed by the ones with Red are second, and so on?

For example, if I have this table:

```
Car           Color 
-----------   ----
Mustang       Red
Thunderbird   Blue
DeLorean      Blue
380SL         Green
```

If I do a normal "SELECT Car FROM AntiqueCars ORDER BY Color," it would return:

```
Thunderbird
DeLorean
380SL
Mustang
```

(Although Thunderbird and DeLorean might end up swapped.)

I'd like to be able to use "SELECT Car FROM AntiqueCars ORDER BY Color(Red, Green, Blue)," and get:

```
Mustang
380SL
Thunderbird
DeLorean
```

Is there any way to do this kind of sorting with values that are normally not recognized as alphabetically or numerically (or temporally) sortable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite and custom order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by)

Comment: Thank you - I was stuck on terms and had spent time Googling, but had not thought of "Custom" for the type of ordering.  I'll wait and let the mods mark it as they wish.  Maybe the different wording in this will help someone else find it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` clause to specify custom ordering:

```
SELECT Car  
FROM AntiqueCars  
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Color = 'red' THEN 1 WHEN Color = 'green' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: Perfect!  Considering I've been up all night on this project and this is one of the last things I need for it, getting a quick answer was a big help!

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it's fulfilling the requirement?