# Yii ORDER BY FIELD() in CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way to create CDbCriteria instance with ORDER BY FIELD() feature?

Column is glncrna_id, id_list: 'GlncRNA10003d', 'GlncRNA10027d', 'GlncRNA20024d'

```
$criteria1->order = "FIELD(glncrna_id, 'GlncRNA10003d', 'GlncRNA10027d', 'GlncRNA20024d')";
```

or

```
$criteria1->order = "FIELD('glncrna_id', GlncRNA10003d, GlncRNA10027d, GlncRNA20024d)";
```

or

```
$criteria1->order = "FIELD('glncrna_id', 'GlncRNA10003d, GlncRNA10027d, GlncRNA20024d')";
```

shows General error: 1 no such function: FIELD

```
$criteria1->order = "FIELD(glncrna_id, GlncRNA10003d, GlncRNA10027d, GlncRNA20024d)";
```

shows not GlncRNA10003d column

How to order result in the id_list ?   I use sqlite database

Comment: Can you go through https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/553 ?

Comment: $criteria->order = "FIELD(name, 'Mobile', 'Utilities') DESC"; is working fine for me. I am using MySql. Which is the database you are using?

Comment: I use sqlite database @AlexJose

Comment: I don't think FIELD function is supported in sqlite databases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$criteria1=new CDbCriteria;  <br/>
$criteria1->order="FIELD(glncrna_id,'GlncRNA10003d','GlncRNA10027d','GlncRNA20024d') DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it, still shows no such function FIELD

Comment: @JesseSiu All I did was edit the post, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cshort for usage of different order by

```
        $sort = new CSort();
        //this should be default order
        $sort->defaultOrder = 't.glncrna_id DESC'; 
        $sort->attributes = array(
            'GlncRNA10003d' => array(
                'asc' => 'GlncRNA10003d asc',
                'desc' => 'GlncRNA10003d desc'
            ),
            'GlncRNA10027d' => array(
                'asc' => 'GlncRNA10003d asc',
                'desc' => 'GlncRNA10027d desc'
            ),
        );

        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ModelName', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => $sort
        ));
```