# Laravel orderbyraw field is not a function sqlite

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-8

I am converting mysql to sqlite but whenever I try to use ordering items with respect to array with

```
$query->whereIn('id',$member_ids) ->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)");
```

I get the following error:

```
General error: 1 no such function: FIELD (SQL: select * from "mst_members" where "id" in (1, 3, 2) order by FIELD(id, 1,3,2))
```

how can I achive sorting by given array in sqlite and laravel 8?

Comment: any reason why you use orderByRaw ?

Comment: There is not any certain reason but I want to order by given array thats why I use it. If you suggest anything else I am open to it.

Comment: There is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by