# SQLite order by field

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to make a query in SQLite that uses a list of contact IDs and is sorted based on the order position of those IDs in the list.

For example:

```
select * from Contact where Contact.ID in (1,3,2,4) 
// then order by (1,3,2,4)
```

Is there any equivalent construct in SQLite like "ORDER BY FIELD" in mysql?
e.g.

```
select * from Contact where Contact.ID in (1,3,2,4) 
order by field (Contact.ID,1,3,2,4)
```

that will also support if given a long list of IDs, not as short as an example above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTACT
WHERE CONTACT.ID IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY 
   CASE ID
      WHEN 4 THEN 1
      WHEN 3 THEN 0
      WHEN 2 THEN 2
      WHEN 1 THEN 3
   END
```

returns in order (3,4,2,1)

Is this what you want?

Comment: No, the result should be sorted based on the order of the IDs in the list given. So if the list is (3,4,2,1), it should not be sorted based on (1,2,3,4), but (3,4,2,1).

Comment: @M.Ridha I edited the query now is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, it will work for a short list, but for a large list (e.g. hundreds of IDs), it's going to be cumbersome to write its long list of ordering code.

Comment: How do you expect to generate an arbitrary list? Is there a priority? if so just add priority column and order on that...

Comment: The list is basically a summary generated based on processing several complex queries and functions. I'm wondering why SQLite does not provide a similar feature like "order by field" as in mysql to simplify the ordering process.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question if you are trying to sort in an arbitrary order you have to have logic to generate said priority no?

Comment: @M.Ridha [Order by field with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091800/order-by-field-with-sqlite?rq=1) might be interest.